# Setting properties in Javascript Classes at execution level

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Example :

```
class MyClass {
    this.text : 'text';
}

console.log(MyClass.text);
```

Is this not allowed? Can I not have classes as objects as you have in Python?

I want to access a class property without an instance.

Is there a workaround while still using the actual `Class` syntax?

Comment: You're not describing the expected behavior. Is that supposed to create a new property on each new instance? On the type itself? Something else? The syntax isn't allowed, but that's not all that relevant. The behavior is what matters.

Comment: @rockstar Have acess to the property in the class, without an instance.

Comment: "Classes" are just functions and functions are objects. But if you never want to instantiate a class there is no reason to use the `class` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, no, you can't (here's the [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)).

You have to use the constructor for that.

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.text = "text";
  }
}
```

[edit] If you don't want an instance, you **should** really just use a 
simple javascript object.

```
let MyClass = {
    text: "text"
};
```

but if you really want the class syntax you would do this:

```
class MyClass {
}

MyClass.text = "text";
```

or

```
class MyClass {
    static get text() {
        return "text";
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to access without an instance, worded the question better now